# How to calculate Mean value and Std Value of an image

Tags: android, image, tensorflow, neural-network, mean

I'v creating an Android app that work with Tensorflow. To feed the image, I need to convert a bitmap into an array of floats by color. I found the following code that does this:

```
float[] floatValues = new float[width * height * 3];
int[] intValues = new int[width * height];

bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    final int val = intValues[i];
    floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = ((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
}
```

I didn't find how to calculate imageMean or imageStd, so someone wrote that I could as well use just

```
floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (val & 0xFF) / 255
```

(for every of the 3 lines)

But it gives the wrong result (same for any input). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961809/same-tensorflow-model-giving-different-results-on-android-and-python) I found that it just gives 0 every time. Thus, I need to figure out how to calculate Mean and Std values. I also heard that these values are different for every color.

Any help highly appreciated.

P.S. dimensions of my images are 250x250, 3 color channels.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. In case you have found a solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

have a try: floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (val & 0xFF) / 255.0f,it's a normalization.
I also have written an Android app that work with Tensorflow. you can refer to my project:https://github.com/tz28/Chinese-number-gestures-recognition/blob/master/README.en-US.md
I hope it will help you.